# Не с кратким прилагательным "похож/а"

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, краткое-прилагательное

*И не похожа на полет походка медленная эта, как будто под ногами плот, а не квадратики паркета!*

Здравствуйте, можете доходчиво объяснить причину раздельного написания? Если не ошибаюсь, в данном случае это скользкое правило с отрицанием положительного признака / утверждением отрицательного? Если да, можете, пожалуйста, разъяснить его на данном примере.

Также приходила мысль, что возможно на написание как-то влияет факт того, что "не похожа" в данном предложении является частью сказуемого?

Comment: Есть много источников, где написано слитно, например на [Грамоте.ру](http://gramota.ru/biblio/reading/?rub=rubric_245&text=27_361) или [здесь](https://rupoem.ru/axmatova/na-shee-melkix.aspx). // Пррр, на сайте принято отмечать все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой. // Добавьте букву Я в слове "медленна".